# Is a sotah woman considered a suicide?

Tags: sotah-secluded-woman, suicide

If a woman drinks the sotah water and dies is her death considered a suicide since she would have known that drinking would kill her?

Comment: She deserves to die as an adulteress.

Comment: @DoubleAA if someone who deserves to die actively participates in their own death, is it a suicide? If you can bring a raiyah either way you'll have a good answer

Comment: @rikitikitembo See Gil Student's article in [_Beit Yitzchak_ vol. 44](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/812782/editor-beis-yitzchak/beis-yitzchak-volume-44/) for sources on the topic.

Comment: @rikitikitembo the Shelias Yaavetz Chelek 1:43 Amnam-in the middle holds of such an opinion http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1408&st=&pgnum=81 ,I learnt this opinion from a shuir on abortion from Rav Glatstein,very interesting shitta which Rav Moshe spoke out very strong in his tshuva in Choshen Mishpat.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10483

Comment: Do we think she would drink it if she *knows* it will kill her?  Perhaps she doesn't believe God will really punish, perhaps she doesn't think what she did qualifies as adultery, perhaps she is unlearned...

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105474/170